# What is angular routing resolve doing?

Tags: angularjs

I was reading this article [Authentication Article](https://vickev.com/#!/article/authentication-in-single-page-applications-node-js-passportjs-angularjs), but I didn't understand this specific part:

```
resolve: { loggedin: checkLoggedin }
```

I was curious if `loggedin` was a predefined name or it can be any naming convention?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [official docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider):

> resolve - `{Object.<string, function>=}` - An optional map of dependencies which should be injected into the controller. If any of these dependencies are promises, the router will wait for them all to be resolved or one to be rejected before the controller is instantiated. If all the promises are resolved successfully, the values of the resolved promises are injected and $routeChangeSuccess event is fired. If any of the promises are rejected the $routeChangeError event is fired. For easier access to the resolved dependencies from the template, the resolve map will be available on the scope of the route, under $resolve (by default) or a custom name specified by the resolveAs property (see below). This can be particularly useful, when working with components as route templates.

So, the example here makes actual use of the optional dependencies map that can be injected to the controller. Specifically, `loggedin` is a map's key and its corresponding value will be assigned from the calculation of the `checkLoggedin` function.

Comment: could I rename loggedin to something else like 'check'

Comment: Yes, but if there;s any other reference to that specific variable, is has also to be updated on the new name. Nonetheless, why do you want to make such a change? I see  no reason and the given from the example name is more descriptive and accurate.

Comment: Oh I just wanted to know if its changeable not saying I would haha. It's a perfectly good name I think too.